# Calculate 20 minute average & best 20 minute average

Tags: python, average

I'm trying to learn Python, with a project where I'm reading data from a bike power meter. Right now I'm just calculating the average power from start to finish, by adding each power reading to a total sum variable, and dividing it with the number of readings.

I'd like to calculate the average power for 20 minutes, and if possible, keep calculating the 20 minute average each 30 seconds after the first 20 minutes, comparing to the previous value and storing it if it's higher than the last, so in the end I could have the higher 20 minute average power that I held during a one hour workout, no matter where it happened in that hour, for example.

Data from the power meter is event based, as far as I can tell it's not a regular intervals, but definitely once a second or faster.
This is the base of my code so far:

```py
def average_power(power, count):
    global PM1_sumwatt
    global PM1_avgwatt
    PM1_sumwatt = PM1_sumwatt + power
    PM1_avgwatt = PM1_sumwatt / count
    PM1_avgLog = open(PM1_avgFile, 'w')
    PM1_avgLog.write("<div id=\"pwr\"> %d W</div>" % (PM1_avgwatt))
    PM1_avgLog.close()

def power_data(eventCount, pedalDiff, pedalPowerRatio, cadence, accumPower, instantPower):
     global PM1_avgcount
     if WCORRECT1: calibpower = instantPower+(CF1w)
     else: calibpower = instantPower*(CF1x)
     power_meter.update(int(calibpower))
     PM1_avgcount = PM1_avgcount + 1
     average_power(int(calibpower), PM1_avgcount)


power  = BicyclePower(readnode, network, callbacks = {'onDevicePaired': device_found,
                                              'onPowerData': power_data})


# Starting PM readings
power.open(ChannelID(PM1, 11, 0))
```

Not quite sure how to tackle this! Any help or pointer is much appreciated!

Comment: What's the input data? Can you show us a piece of your code?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this is not a code-writing or tutorial site, and we ask that you provide a [mcve] for your issue including sample input, sample output, and code for what you've tried so far based on your own research

Comment: Keep the power readings in a list.  If you take one reading every 30 seconds, then the last 40 items in the list will be the most recent 20 minutes worth.

Comment: I just added the main code I'm using. First function is the overall average calculation, called by the second function. The second function is called on each event from the BicyclePower object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are reading data in real time, I assume you are reading the data in a while loop:

```py
sum = 0
number_of_readings = 0
while True:  # forever
    new_value = input()  # here I read from the console input
    sum += new_value
    number_of_readings += 1
    average = sum/number_of_readings 
    print(average)
```

Here I type a number in the console and press enter to simulate your bike power meter.

```
>>> 1
1.0
>>> 3
2.0
>>> 4
2.6666666666666665
>>> 2
2.5
```

---

Now, if you wants to make a moving average, you must store the readings that you wants to average. This is because you want to remove them later, when they will be too old. A [list](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list) is perfect for that:

Here is a solution averaging the last `n` readings:

```py
n = 2
Last_n_readings = []
while True:  # forever
    # add a new reading
    new_value = int(input())  # here I read from the console input
    Last_n_readings.append(new_value)
    # discard an old one (except when we do not have enough readings yet)
    if len(Last_n_readings) > n:
        Last_n_readings.pop(0)
    # print the average of all the readings still in the list
    print(sum(Last_n_readings) / len(Last_n_readings))
```

Which gives:

```py
>>> 1
1.0
>>> 3
2.0
>>> 4
3.5
>>> 2
3.0
```

Note that lists are not very efficient when removing elements near the start, so there are more effective ways to do this (circular buffers), but I try to keep it simple ;)

You could use this by guessing how many readings/seconds you have and choose `n` so you average over 20 minutes.
If you want to truly average all the result which are less than 20 minutes ago, you need to not only record the readings but also the times when you red them, so you can remove the old readings wen they get more than 20 minutes old. If this is what you need, tell me and I will expand my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you! The readings from the power meter are event based, I don't think they happen quite at regular intervals, but I might try to write some sample code to store readings for a few minutes and see if I can come to an average number of readings per minute. This would make it so that I could use your code!

Comment: Ok! I've implemented this in my current main program and seems to be working. I gathered timestamped data and estimated 44 readings per minute. From there it was pretty much using your code as is. Quick and dirty, but it works. Also have the pandas solution working, but more for post workout analysis rather than running live in the main program! Thanks @Raphael!

Comment: You are welcome, and thanks for the update, very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas dataframe to store the power output for each instance.

Considering that you receive a value each 30 second, you can store them all in data frame.

Then calculate a 40 data point moving average using rolling function in python.

Take the max value you get after the rolling function, this would be your final result.

refer this for doc : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look! I'm not receiving a value from the power meter every 30secs, much faster than that. What I said is I'd like to compare the 20min average every 30 seconds and compare to the previous 20min average, store if higher. The data from the power meter is event based so I don't think it comes at regular intervals.

Comment: In that case you can convert the events to nearest 30 second and insert to the dataframe. In case you don't get any event for a particular 30 sec window insert a NA. after that you can use the rolling function. 
Let me know if I was not clear or if you have trouble implementing it.

Comment: I have setup the main program to output data to a csv file: just datetime for the first column, power1 and power2 for 2nd and 3rd columns. Using the datetime as an index I can already calculate several mean /max values over time and plot graphs using pandas on a separate program that reads the csv. Pandas is very interesting and powerful, still much to learn! But glad that I got results! Thanks @solve-it!